# Change Color of Only Certain Links WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

Certain links are hard to read on this page:
http://jackswebdesign.co.uk/adl/portfolio-type/

Commercial, Kitchen Modelling, etc.

I've tried adding this to the style.css file

```
meta-progression-port a:link {
  color: black !important;
}
```

But it won't work.

Comment: Is that just a typo in your question, or is that in your code as well? You're missing a leading period in `meta-progression-port`. It should be `.meta-progression-port a:link`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not setting a selector. Is meta-progression-port an ID or class? There should be '#' or '.' in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the "." to target the class (which is what "meta-progression-port" is)

Your CSS should be:

```
.meta-progression-port a:link {
  color: black !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the big links:

```
.portfolio-index-title a {
    color: #000;
}
```

For the smaller links:

```
.meta-progression-port ul li a {
    color: #000;
}
```

Where #000 - is the color you want.